# Can I supply gitattributes from the command line?

Tags: git, git-config, gitattributes

I have the following in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "haskell"]
  textconv=brittany
```

I want to invoke diff with this textconv occasionally, but not always, on `.hs` files.

If I put this in my `.gitattributes`, then `brittany` will always be invoked when diffing `.hs` files:

```
*.hs diff=haskell
```

But I only want to do this sometimes. Is there a way I can tell `git` from the command line to use the attribute `diff=haskell`, or tell it to use a particular `.gitattributes` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out `textconv=brittany` from `.gitconfig`, so that `git diff`(and other commands that generate diff like `git show` and `git log -p`) on `.hs` files does not invoke `brittany`. When you want to invoke it, use

```
git -c diff.haskell.textconv=brittany diff
```